# The ring of power series in z with a positive radius of convergence

Tags: complex-analysis, commutative-algebra

Let $A$ be the ring of power series in $z$ with a positive radius of convergence, where all coefficients are complex numbers.

1. What is the name of $A$? Does it have a special name?
2. I want to show that if $f(z)\in A$ has nonzero constant, then $f(z)$ is invertible in $A$. How can I prove this? I know that any formal power series is invertible if the constant is not zero. But how can I show that the radius of convergence of $1/f(z)$ is positive?
3. How can I know this result from complex analysis? I studied complex analysis for a semester, but I don't remember whether I learned this or not. I thought I have heard some similar thing, but I can't find out it in the textbook(Silverman)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I thought I might as well make an earlier comment into an answer:

1. I'd call it the ring of germs of holomorphic/analytic functions at $0$.
2. Look at the explicit inverse formal power series and recall the formula for the radius of convergence.
3. Every such power series represents a holomorphic function in some neighborhood of $0$. Now use that $1/f$ is holomorphic wherever $f$ is nonzero and the identification of holomorphic functions with functions that are locally developable as power series.

---

**Added:**

You asked about proving that the formal inverse of a power series with positive radius of convergence is again a power series with positive radius of convergence "without using complex analysis". This can be done with a nice trick that goes back to Abel, Hurwitz and Weierstrass, using comparison with geometric series  only.

**Step 1.** A formal power series $f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n z^n$ has positive radius of convergence $\rho \gt 0$ if and only if either one of the following three conditions holds:

1. We have $\rho^{-1} = \limsup\limits_{n \to \infty}\; |a_n|^{1/n} \lt \infty$.
2. There  are $q \gt 0$ and $C \geq 0$ such that $|a_n| q^n \leq C$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.
3. There is $r \gt 0$ such that $|a_n| \leq r^n$ for all $n \geq 1$.

This should be clear from the proof of the formula for the radius of convergence.

**Step 2.** Let $f(z)= 1 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n z^n$ have positive radius of convergence. Then the inverse formal power series $g(z) = 1 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b_n z^n$ with $b_0 = 1$ and $b_n = -\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i b_{n-i}$ for $n \geq 1$ has positive radius of convergence as well.

By step 1 there is $r \gt 0$ such that $|a_n| \leq r^n$ for all $n \geq 1$. Note that
$|b_1| = |a_1|  \leq \frac{1}{2} \cdot 2 r$ and by induction $$|b_n| \leq \frac{1}{2} (2r)^n.$$
Indeed, 
$$|b_n| \leq \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} |a_i|\,|b_{n-i}| + |a_{n}| \leq \frac{1}{2} \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} r^i (2r)^{n-i} + r^n \leq \frac{1}{2}(2r)^n.$$ 
Putting $q = 1/(2r)$ we get $|b_n| q^n \leq 1/2$, and we conclude by step 1 again.

**Step 3.**
The element $f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n$ of $A$ is a unit if and only if $a_{0} \neq 0$.

Reduce to step 2.

Comment: If you need more details, I'll be happy to add them, but I suggest that you try it first on your own.

Comment: For answer2, if $f(z)=\sum a_n z^n$, the inverse of it is $g(z)= \sum b_n z^n $ where $b_0 = a_{0}^{-1}, b_n = -a_{0}^{-1} \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i b_{n-i}$. But how can I know that $\limsup b_n$>0?

Comment: Hint: if $f$ is a formal power series with positive radius of convergence, then $f$ defines a holomorphic function in some disk of radius $\delta>0$ centered at the origin. Moreover, since $f(0)\neq 0$, the continuity of $f$ implies that we can choose $\delta>0$ sufficiently small such that $f$ has no zeros in this disc. The function $\frac{1}{f}$ is now holomorphic in this disc. Hence $\frac{1}{f}$ has a formal power series representation in this disc.

Comment: @Amitesh Yes, I understand it now after reviewing some of complex analysis. (I specially missed that $1/f$ is holomorphic if $f$ has no zero, just by the quotient rule $(1/f)'=-f'/f^2$.) But is there any proof with the explicit inverse formal power series, not using the complex analysis background?

Comment: @gobi: see edit.

Comment: @Theo Thanks! I got it.

Answer (score 8):

Theo's (excellent) answer is sufficient; however, let me also add the following exercises which I think are useful if you wish to develop a deeper understanding of the ring $A$:

***Definition***

A ring $R$ is said to be a ***local ring*** if it has a unique maximal ideal $m$. In other words, the ring $R$ is local if every proper ideal of $R$ is contained in $m$.

***Exercise 1***: If $R$ is local with unique maximal ideal $m$, prove that every element of $R$ *not in* $m$ is a unit in $R$.

***Exercise 2***: Prove that if the set of non-units in a commutative ring $A$ is an ideal in $A$, then $A$ is a local ring.

***Exercise 3***: Prove that the ring $A$ of your question is a local ring. Moreover, prove that the unique maximal ideal of $A$ is a principal ideal. (Hint: the set of all elements of $A$ with constant term $0$ is an ideal; prove that it is the unique maximal ideal of $A$. Theo's answer and exercise 2 are relevant.)

***Exercise 4***: Prove that every proper non-zero ideal of $A$ (of your question) is a power of $m$, the unique maximal ideal of $A$. (Recall that if $I$ is an ideal in a ring $A$, the power $I^n$ ($n\geq 1$) is defined to be the ideal generated by the set of all products consisting of $n$ terms where each term is an element of $I$.) In particular, we say that $A$ is a ***discrete valuation ring*** (DVR is a common abbreviation).

***Exercise 5***: Let $A$ be an *arbitrary* local ring with unique maximal ideal $m$. Is it true that every proper non-zero ideal of $A$ is a power of $m$? If $A$ is a Noetherian ring, is it true that the intersection of all powers of $m$ is the zero ideal? (This question is difficult.)

***Exercise 6***: Let $x\in \mathbb{R}$ and consider the set of all ordered pairs $(f,U)$ where $U$ is open and $f:U\to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous. We define an equivalence relation on this set by setting $(f,U)\equiv (g,V)$ if $f|W=g|W$ for some open subset $W\subseteq U\cap V$. Let us define a ring structure on the set of all equivalence classes $A$ by the rules: $(f,U)+(g,V)=(f+g,U\cap V)$ and $(f,U)\times (g,V)=(f\times g,U\cap V)$. Prove that these operations are well-defined and prove that the ring $A$ in question is a local ring. (Hint: The set of all equivalence classes corresponding to representatives of the form $(f,U)$ such that $f(x)=0$ is the unique maximal ideal of $A$.)

***Exercise 7***: Is the result of the above exercise true if the word "continuous" is deleted throughout? Is the result of the above exercise true if the words "continuous" *and* "open" are deleted throughout? Is the result of the above exercise true if the word "continuous" is replaced by either "differentiable", "smooth" or "analytic"?

***Exercise 8***: Is every proper non-zero ideal in the ring of exercise 5 a power of the unique maximal ideal of this ring?

I hope these exercises are useful! (They are all important since they provide good practice with the notion of a *local ring*; local rings are ubiquituous in commutative algebra.)

Comment: Wow, that's what I call a nice and informative answer! Certainly useful since the question is tagged commutative algebra by the OP. By the way: From your answers I've seen so far, I wouldn't have guessed that your age is what it is, that's quite impressive. Thanks for the nice words in the first sentence!

Comment: @gobi Of course, if you are stuck with any of the above exercises, please feel very free to comment and I will help you.

Comment: Dear Theo, thank you very much for the compliments!

Comment: Thanks for really good exercises. And I can't believe your age, too. I think I can solve exercises 1~4. 1~2 is elementary, and there's also a solution in [CrazyProject](http://crazyproject.wordpress.com/2010/10/06/if-the-set-of-all-nonunits-in-a-commutative-ring-is-an-ideal-then-it-forms-the-unique-maximal-ideal/). 3~4 is simliar to Atiyah's Ex6.4, from which I wrote this question. But other exercises need time to solve.

Comment: @gobi I should emphasize that exercise 5 is not easy (in fact, it is a theorem known as the "Krull intersection theorem") but I think that as one progresses in one's study of commutative algebra (or, indeed, any branch of mathematics), one should start proving difficult theorems on one's own. This is why I gave the exercise. However, if you are truly stuck, it might be better to focus mainly on the other exercises.